# Error : Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> ( TABLE_PER_CLASS )

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, class-table-inheritance

I am using Hibernate to save entities where all entities are inherited from a base abstract entity. For all concrete Entities there are database tables respectively, with autoincrement primary key column. But using GenerationType as "AUTO" or "IDENTITY" gives error. I want all records in database tables representing each concrete entity class, should have sequentially incremented ID values.

**com.something.SuperClass:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class SuperClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -695503064509648117L;

    long confirmationCode;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // Causes exception!!!
    public long getConfirmationCode() {
        return confirmationCode;
    }

    public void setConfirmationCode(long confirmationCode) {
        this.confirmationCode = confirmationCode;
    }
}
```

**com.something.SubClass:**

```
@Entity
public abstract class Subclass extends SuperClass {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8623159397061057722L;

    String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Gives me this exception:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key
generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: com.something.SuperClass
What's the best and most convenient way for me to generate the ID's? I do not want to change my inheritance strategy.
```

I know it can be solved if I change GenerationType from "AUTO" to "TABLE", but the issue with this solutions is, generated keys are not in exact sequence. It leaves big gap between keys.

I am looking for solution which will allow all tables to use Auto Incremental values generated by Mysql AutoIncrement primary column.

Thanks in advance to all.

P.S.: I have already gone through following posts:
[Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> ( TABLE_PER_CLASS )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916169/cannot-use-identity-column-key-generation-with-union-subclass-table-per-clas)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> ( TABLE\_PER\_CLASS )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916169/cannot-use-identity-column-key-generation-with-union-subclass-table-per-clas)

Comment: I have this same issue. Have you found any clues about it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you mix "table-per-class" inheritance and GenerationType.Auto. In a "table-per-class" strategy you use one table per class and each one has an ID.

I Had the same problem and I fixed that by replacing     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) with GenerationType.TABLE

the final code looks like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class SuperClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -695503064509648117L;

    long confirmationCode;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public long getConfirmationCode() {
        return confirmationCode;
    }

    public void setConfirmationCode(long confirmationCode) {
        this.confirmationCode = confirmationCode;
    }
}
```