# How to keep data in MySQL and change the @Id from GenerationType.AUTO to GenerationType.TABLE

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a similar problem like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916169/cannot-use-identity-column-key-generation-with-union-subclass-table-per-clas). But my application is running on MySQL with working data.

What is the best practice to refactor the application with an existing database which is populated with data?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy nor the `TABLE` generator scale very well.

The `TABLE` generator uses [row-level locks and a separate transaction][2] every time it needs to fetch a new identifier value. That puts pressure on the connection pool since you need two connections whenever you try to insert an entity.

The `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy generates suboptimal queries when using polymorphic JPQL. Use `SINGLE_TABLE` or `JOINED` instead.