# How can I combine TABLE_PER_CLASS and GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, persistence

**Dear future reader**: After working through [Sannes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47510044/881272) and the link he provides, I decided to go with a Sequence instead. Newer Hibernates take care that it works on MySQL as well.

---

I have an `abstract` class that contains some basic values that I want to have in all my entities (such as id, creation date, creation user, etc.). Currently I struggle with the combination of having a table per concrete class and having its id work.

It seems I can either have a table per class OR a single place where I configure the ID, but not both. That seems very odd and unlikely to me, so I want to make sure that this is the case.

Versions that might be relevant: hibernate 5, mysql 5.5, java 1.8, spring 4.3.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GeneralData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    // getters, setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

Example subclass:

```
@Entity
public class ExampleClass extends GeneralData {
    // own values, constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Error I get:

```
Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: org.example.ExampleClass
```

Things I've tried:

- I have tried to make `GeneralData` an `@Entity`, but that didn't help.
- [I tried to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/916169/881272) use a `GenerationType.TABLE` but that failed because the key is too big. (Also, I'd rather not have this, IDENTITY is what I want) Error: `Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`

I'd rather not move the id column to each and every concrete class. I'm totally fine if the ID is unique only for a single table and not via the whole dependency tree.

If I should upgrade my libs, database, etc. please keep in mind that such can only be done with a lot of extra work (for internal reasons). This would be a last resort and I'd like to see some evidence that it helps first.

Comment: You cannot use Id property in base class. It should be in the entity class representing the specific table.

Comment: @HarKrishan So I have heard, but that makes no sense to me. So I'd like some evidence that this is true before believing it.

Comment: In table-per-concrete-class strategy,  two tables are involved for the subclasses. Each table defines columns for all properties of the class, including inherited properties. 
The limitation of this approach is that if a property is mapped on the superclass, the column name must be the same on all subclass tables. The identity generator strategy is not allowed in union subclass inheritance. The primary key seed has to be shared across all unioned subclasses of a hierarchy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A requirement for all child objects of the same parent entity is that they have unique IDs among them.

Say for example you have a parent Entity `GeneralData` and then store subtype `A` with id=1.
This would be perfectly legal:

```
GeneralData loaded = entitymanager.find( GeneralData.class, 1 );
```

And of course the type of `loaded` will be `A`: the subclass. *The mapping must ensure there is no ambiguity: NO other subclass must be allowed to also use "1" as an ID, even if it's mapped in a different table*.

In your case you're asking Hibernate to store each different subtype of `GeneralData` into its own separate Table.

You're also asking that MySQL - which is not aware of these tables being related in any way - to assign unique identifiers automatically.

It's not possible to instruct MySQL that each of these tables need to use the same `Identity` "sequence" as these are not real Sequences: so this mapping is illegal! It would get you in trouble as it will assign overlapping IDs to different subtypes of your parent entity, violating the semantics described above.

This is a good example of the limitations of using IDENTITY; besides, IDENTITY is not very efficient as it implies that Hibernate needs to write the entity immediately as soon as it's persisted rather than being able to more efficiently postpone the flush operation to a more fitting time, and so doing possibly batch writes or skip them altogether (especially if transactions are aborted, but also if you update the entity after the persist but still in the same transaction).

I'd suggest to have a look at different [Identifier generator strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers) for such hierarchies, and in particular [Optimizers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-optimizer) might vastly improve the performance of your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains the behaviour. I tried moving the id to the subclasses, but that also failed. Is that related or more likely that I did something wrong? Also can I somehow disconnect the elements? (e.G. not make `GeneralData` being loadable by entityManager?)

Comment: You'd have the same conceptual problem: two entities in the same polymorhipc hierarchy yet unable to share a single, consistent source of unique IDs. That's a no-go.

Comment: I ended up with a Sequence instead. Maybe you post that at the beginning of your wonderful answer as it solves the goal of the question (even though not the question title). That way it will show up in the excerpts of search engines and people will find it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 different table per concrete class mapping :

- with implicit polymorphism, it’s not possible to use polymorphic queries but you can use the IDENTITY strategy (that is not very efficient as pointed out by Sanne). The identifier can be defined in the superclass or in the subclasses.
- with union, does not permit the IDENTITY strategy (the reasons were clearly explained by Sanne). The identifier have to be defined in the superclass

For the first one the mapping is

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GeneralData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    ....
}

@Entity
public class ExampleClass extends GeneralData {
    ...
}
```

while for the second one the mapping is

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class GeneralData implements Serializable {
....
}

@Entity
public class ExampleClass extends GeneralData {
   ...
}
```

Comment: First block returns with error: "No identifier specified for entity. fqn.ExampleClass"